# Slick slider not working when initialSlide is set

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

I can't figure out why the slides do not slide when I have an `initialSlide` set. I'm referring to the docs at https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/, but couldn't figure out what the problem is.

```js
$('.container').slick({
  initialSlide: 4,
  infinite: false,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 120px;
}

.slide {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="slide">1</div>
  <div class="slide">2</div>
  <div class="slide">3</div>
  <div class="slide">4</div>
  <div class="slide">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is working, all that's wrong is that you are setting the initial slide to the last one (index 4 is the 5th slide) so there is nothing to slide to.

Comment: @FluffyKitten, in that case, sliding to the previous slides should work, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the initial slide to `4` (i.e. index 4 is slide #5) - this is the last slide in your carousel. The problem is that your carousel is showing 3 slides, so you want the initial slide to be #3 which has index: `2`:

(total slides - slidesToShow) = 5-3 = 2

If you set `initialSlide: 2` this will still show the last 3 slides but it also sets up the "previous" button to go to slide #2 which will trigger a scroll. (The Next button won't have any effect of course, because you are showing the last slide and have `infinite:false`)

**Working Example:**

```js
$('.container').slick({
  initialSlide: 2,
  infinite: false,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 120px;
}

.slide {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="slide">1</div>
  <div class="slide">2</div>
  <div class="slide">3</div>
  <div class="slide">4</div>
  <div class="slide">5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is to work

$('.container').slick({
infinite: false,
slidesToShow: 2,
slidesToScroll: 1,
initialSlide: 3
})

you have 5 slides, but the initial one you specified is 4, and at the same time show 3. but the initial 1 is slide 2, the Initial 4 is slide 5, but slidesToShow: 3. the slider doesn't have any spare slides to show

while I was writing the answer it is already given in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Since 2014 initialSlide not working in responsive config, so can use

```
$('.selector').slick('slickGoTo', 5);
```